# Create modern team site in SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

I found some [articles](https://gautamdsheth.wordpress.com/2017/11/21/create-modern-team-and-communication-sites-in-sharepoint-online-using-csom/comment-page-1/#comment-15) which are explaining creating modern sites with CSOM. But I am not able to find in JavaScript to use in SPFx. 
Creating modern sites is supported with SPFx? Any PnP extension available for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the PnPJS to create modern team and communication sites.

For that, simply add the below packages:

```
npm install @pnp/logging @pnp/common @pnp/odata @pnp/sp --save
```

After that, you can add the below import statement:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
```

And in the webpart, you can use it as below to create modern sites:

1) Modern communication sites:

```
sp.site.createCommunicationSite(
            "Comm Site Title",
            1033,
            true,
            "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/commSite",
            ).then(d => {
                console.log(d);
            });
```

2) Modern team site:

```
sp.site.createModernTeamSite(
        "displayName",
        "alias",
        true,
        1033,
        "description",
        "",
        ["user1@tenant.onmicrosoft.com","user2@tenant.onmicrosoft.com","user3@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"])
        .then(d => {
            console.log(d);
        });
```

Reference - [PnPJS Sites](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/sites/)

Comment: I don't see the point to have two identical answers.. so deleted mine despite I answered a bit earlier than you...

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with the most recent version (1.2.6) of [PnPjs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/sites/#create-a-modern-team-site) library:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";

sp.site.createModernTeamSite(
        "displayName",
        "alias",
        true,
        1033,
        "description",
        "HBI",
        ["user1@tenant.onmicrosoft.com","user2@tenant.onmicrosoft.com","user3@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"])
        .then(d => {
            console.log(d);
        });
```